# Is it still possible to run Safari 6 in 32bit on MacOS 10.8?

Tags: macos, safari, 32-bit

I tried the ways i know:

1. Get Info - 32bit Mode - Start ==> runs in 64 bit
2. arch -i386 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOs/Safari ==> results in error

is it still somehow possible to run Safari in 32bit ? I need it in order to work with ManyCam which can only operate in 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Lion abandoned 32-bit application mode.

Comment: thats what i thought, strange that it offers the option to select 32bit mode

Comment: This is strange… :-/

Comment: that seems to be the sad truth as far as my research goes